# can I orderby one custom field and meta_query another in the same query

Tags: customization

I have a custom query and I am filtering out events by custom field: event-month.  I simple filter our the events that dont have a month_number = to date("n");

Its a pretty great little query, but I need to orderby another custom field, event_date.

Do I need a custom function or something to get this done.  I simply want to orderby => event_date

but I am currently using event-month for my query.

```
<?php 
        $event_query = new WP_Query(
        array( 
          'post_type'   => 'event',        // only query events
          'meta_key'    => 'event-month',  // load up the event_date meta
          'order_by'    => '',
          'order'       => 'asc',         // ascending, so earlier events first
          'meta_query'  => array(
             array(         // restrict posts based on meta values
              'key'     => 'event-month',  // which meta to query
              'value'   => date("n"),  // value for comparison
              'compare' => '=',          // method of comparison
              'type'    => 'NUMERIC'         // datatype, we don't want to compare the string values
            ) // meta_query is an array of query ites
           ) // end meta_query array
          ) // end array
        ); // close WP_Query constructor call
```

?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite `meta_key` being deprecated, it is still required to get the orderby to work correctly.

First and foremost though, there's an error with your code, and that's in using `order_by` and not `orderby` (there's no underscore in the orderby arg).

Give this a shot and see how it works out for you.

```
$event_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'   => 'event',
    'meta_key'    => 'event-month',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array( 
            'key'     => 'event-month',
            'value'   => date("n"),
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    ),
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'       => 'asc', 
) );
```

If you want to add a second meta key, and sort by that key, just ensure that key is inside the `meta_key` arg, eg.

```
$event_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'   => 'event',
    'meta_key'    => 'some-key',
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array( 
            'key'     => 'some-key',
            'value'   => 'whatever',
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array( 
            'key'     => 'event-month',
            'value'   => date("n"),
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    ),
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'       => 'asc', 
) );
```

Odd that you should need `meta_key` for the sort, but i don't see the orderby being respected without it, i can see how the query appears inside [debug bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/)'s queries tab and as far as i can tell `meta_key` is currently required to get a proper sort on `meta_value`.

Comment: t31os, this looks right.  I am not 100% sure hot to move forward but this is pointing me in the right direction.  Is there any connection between the initial meta_key/value and the meta_key/value in the meta_query? OR is it essentially saying, find all by these params then compare against the meta_query?  If the later is the case then I could simply put event_date in the initial meta_key and then handle the event-month compare in the meta query. Does that make sense?

Comment: The standalone `meta_key` is purely for the sort order, `meta_query` does all of the work though, ie. figuring out which posts match the given criteria. Removing the `meta_key` arg would just result in you losing the `meta_value` sort order.

Comment: t31os, thanks for the help.  I have it working just fine.

Comment: This answer was just incredibly helpful to me! The codex does not explain this at all and because `meta_key` was marked as deprecated, I was avoiding it like the plague.

Comment: Just to add something to this gr8 answer - for those who wish to sort by a numeric value replace 'orderby' => 'meta_value' to  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'

Answer (score 0):

I found that t31os's answer works, but only if included with:

```
 'posts_per_page'   => -1,
```

in the $args ...

Not including it did weird things like removing records that were meant to be in result set.

Answer (score -1):

Remove 'meta_key' from params. It doesn't work in WP 3.1

Comment: Thanks for the note: but any ideas on how to order the results by a second key/value?

Comment: Not true, it's just a deprecated parameter, it still functions as intended however. You will also need the parameter to get a proper sort, despite the deprecation(unless that bug has now been rectified in core).