# Sort by multiple options in custom field

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

With use of the Advanced Custom Fields plugin I created a select dropdown which contains 6 membership types. All of my 'listings' using this custom field are assigned one of the 6.

[image]

I'd like to display all 'listings' by:

Ultimate Plus
Ultimate
Professional
Commercial
Business
Free

In this particular order, so those paying for the highest level membership have their 'listing' appear at the top of the page.

I expected it to be similar to this which I just found but unsure exactly:

```
// args
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'directory_listings',
'meta_key'   => 'free',
'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
'order'      => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => '#',
        'value'   => array( #, # ),
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ),
),
);

// query
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        ldl_get_template_part('listing', 'compact');
        ldl_get_featured_posts();
    }
    ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you make your choices list a value=>label list, this should work: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11454/20807

Instead of your current list,

```
1 : Ultimate Plus
2 : Ultimate
3 : Professional
4 : Commercial
5 : Business
6 : Free
```

It can also be in the order that you currently have

```
6 : Free
5 : Business
4 : Commercial
3 : Professional
2 : Ultimate
1 : Ultimate Plus
```

Then, the `meta_key` / `orderby` combo should get you where you want.

More info about ACF's Select field type: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/